# Pass multiple paramters in href javascript attribute?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I pass a second parameter into this?

`href="javascript:selectTable(\''.$booking['reservation_date'].'\');"`

Answer (score 0):

Try using onClick instead of href.

```
onclick="selectTable(\''.$booking['reservation_date'].'\'); otherFunction();"
```

Answer (score 0):

href, you have to use it for redirect user, try use onclick attribute, if your tag be  use the attribute `href=javascript:;`.

```
onclick="selectTable(\''.$booking['reservation_date'].'\');"
```